# mysql - Subquery returns more than 1 row error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am still having issues with my sub query returning multiple rows in some cases and not others. I have looked over some of the suggested questions but they still don't match my issue. Users in those examples had been returning more than one value in their sub query, not putting delimiters, or were just using the wrong syntax for their situation. I have placed my code below as I can not understand where the issue is happening.

```
SELECT q.id, q.title, (SELECT a.answer FROM v_events_abstracts_answers AS a WHERE a.question_id=q.id AND uniq_id=2013121713133221), q.code 
                FROM v_events_abstracts_questions AS q 
                    WHERE q.event_id=193 
                    ORDER BY q.ordering, q.id ASC
```

I am not just asking for "debugging" I would like to understand how this issue arises for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query:

```
SELECT q.id, q.title,
       (SELECT a.answer
        FROM v_events_abstracts_answers AS a
        WHERE a.question_id=q.id AND uniq_id=2013121713133221
       ),
       q.code 
FROM v_events_abstracts_questions AS q 
WHERE q.event_id=193 
ORDER BY q.ordering, q.id ASC;
```

What is unclear about the error message?  The subquery:

```
       (SELECT a.answer
        FROM v_events_abstracts_answers AS a
        WHERE a.question_id=q.id AND uniq_id=2013121713133221
       ),
```

Is returning more than one row.  This subquery is being used in a context where a *scalar subquery* is allowed.  A *scalar subquery* is one that returns one row with one column.  The results are then treated like a single value.

You can fix this by aggregation or using `limit`.  Here is one way:

```
       (SELECT group_concat(a.answer)
        FROM v_events_abstracts_answers AS a
        WHERE a.question_id=q.id AND uniq_id=2013121713133221
       ) as answers,
```

Comment: @soccermanstan . . . That makes it a correlated subquery.  Apparently, one or more questions have two or more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding using the correlated sub query you could do:-

```
SELECT q.id, q.title, a.answer, q.code 
FROM v_events_abstracts_questions AS q 
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_events_abstracts_answers AS a
ON a.question_id = q.id
AND a.uniq_id = 2013121713133221
WHERE q.event_id = 193 
ORDER BY q.ordering, q.id ASC
```

The question is that if a question has more than 1 answer for a unique id then how do you decide which one to chose?